# How can I see the list of differing commits on one file between two branches?

Tags: git, version-control

Is there any way to do this in git? Just see a list of the differing commits between two branches, I can't just look at the logs, because there have been dozens of different commits over several months to the two branches.

Answer (score 2):

Use a filespec when invoking git log:

```
git log commit1 commit2 -- file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Play with the options `--left-right` and `--cherry-pick` to `git log`.

And specify the file name, as mentioned by Michael Krelin and knittl.

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying path to `git log`?